# how to check url for JSON data every few seconds when app is closed(Android)

Tags: android, json, android-service

I want to write an app that checks a URL for JSON data and if data was something specific, an activity starts automatically even when the app is closed (like an alarm).

I wrote a foreground service and it doesn't work. Probably not even the best way anyway:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent notificationIntent= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,ID)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(true)
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        FetchJason fetchJason = new FetchJason();
                        fetchJason.execute();
                        startForeground(1,notification);
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        MainActivity.textView.setText("bbb");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }).start();



        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

How can I develop an app like that? How should I proceed?

Comment: Making a Web request every 5 seconds is very bad for battery life, which is why Google goes to great lengths to prevent developers from doing stuff like that.

Comment: This is a very bad idea to check every few seconds, you can always use `WorkManager` & implement your logic in a `PeriodicWorkRequest` to check every once in a while, minimum time is around 15 min. & execution is not 100% guaranteed at exact 15 min. interval. Another option is to use FirebaseCloudMessaging, so whenever your Json changes (if you own that file & server), just send either a Notification Message or a Data Message.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with AsyncTask,

```
    public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {       
                    try {
                        PerformBackgroundTask performBackgroundTask = new PerformBackgroundTask();
                        // PerformBackgroundTask this class is the class that extends AsynchTask 
                        performBackgroundTask.execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000); //execute in every 5000 ms
}
```